# Snake Ladder using BFS

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, data-structures, graph

Given a snake ladder board, we have to find the minimum distance of the last vertex from the 0th vertex. ( at 0th vertex we throw the dice and move ahead)

Read about the problem here -> [LINK](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/snake-ladder-problem-2/)

**My code:**

```
from collections import defaultdict

global INT_MAX
INT_MAX = 3 ** 38


class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertList = defaultdict(list)

    def addEdge(self, u, v):
        self.vertList[u].append(v)

    def distanceBFS(self, src, target):
        queue = []
        queue.append(src)
        distanceDict = {}
        for v in self.vertList:
            distanceDict[v] = INT_MAX
        distanceDict[src] = 0
        visited = set()

        while (len(queue) > 0):
            curr = queue.pop(0)
            visited.add(curr)

            for vertex in self.vertList[curr]:
                if vertex not in visited:
                    queue.append(vertex)
                    distanceDict[vertex] = distanceDict[curr] + 1

        print(distanceDict[target])

    def solveSnakesLadder(self):
        snakeLadderDict = {2: 13, 5: 2, 9: 18, 18: 11, 17: -13, 20: -14, 24: -8, 25: 10, 32: -2, 34: -22}
        # we have 36 boxes --> i
        # we can throw a dice at each of these 36 boxes and it can be from 1 to 6
        # j is new position on the board after throwing a dice
        for i in range(0, 37):
            for dice in range(1, 7):
                j = i + dice
                if j in snakeLadderDict:
                    j += snakeLadderDict[j]
                if j <= 36:
                    self.addEdge(i, j)
        self.distanceBFS(0, 36)


g = Graph()
g.solveSnakesLadder()
```

**Current output:**

```
10
```

**Correct Output:**

```
4
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is it something to do with the logic? I could have also checked for the value in the distanceDict before appending in the queue but the visited set does the same thing!

Comment: You should add the problem description.  It's helpful to add `algorithm` tag too.

Comment: Sure! Doing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bascially, the problem is with the following block of code:

```
    queue.append(src)
    distanceDict[src] = 0
    visited = set()
    while (len(queue) > 0):
        curr = queue.pop(0)
        visited.add(curr)

        for vertex in self.vertList[curr]:
            if vertex not in visited:
                queue.append(vertex)
                distanceDict[vertex] = distanceDict[curr] + 1
```

I will try to explain the same with the following basic graph:

[image]

Suppose, you need to find the shortest path from vertex `1` to vertex `3` in the below graph. Using the above implementation, you'll have the following iterations:

1. Add vertex `1` to Queue `Q` and set its distance to `0`
2. Next, you pop `1` from `Q` in the `while` loop and mark it as visited
3. Next, you visit all its neighbors and add them to the queue `Q`.

So, at this point, the state of different objects will be as follows:

We have vertices `2` and `3` in the queue `Q` and the `distance` dictionary will be as `distance[1] = 0, distance[2] = 1, distance[3] = 1` and this is where the problem starts since we haven't yet added vertices `2` and `3` to the `visited` array and we will start updating the distance of these vertices again in the next iteration if we visit them again from other neighbors.

4. Going back to our algorithm again, now we again go to the start of the `while` loop and `pop` vertex `2` from it and mark it as visited.
5. When we next go through its unvisited neighbors, we will revisit `3` again which we have already visited and will update the `distance` dictionary with the incorrect value.

The state of different objects after visiting vertex `2` and its neighbors will be as follows:

We have vertices `3` in the queue and the distance dictionary will be as `distance[1] = 0, distance[2] = 1, distance[3] = 2`. `distance[3]` has been wrongly updated as we have seen from the iteration.

The fix however is pretty straight forward where in we need to mark the vertex as visited just after we have visited it so that we don't put it again in the queue through some other neighbour.

By now, you would have already guessed that the right implementation for the BFS function should be as given:

```
from collections import defaultdict

global INT_MAX
INT_MAX = 3 ** 38


class Graph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vertList = defaultdict(list)

    def addEdge(self, u, v):
        self.vertList[u].append(v)

    def distanceBFS(self, src, target):
        queue = []
        queue.append(src)
        distanceDict = {}
        for v in self.vertList:
            distanceDict[v] = INT_MAX
        distanceDict[src] = 0
        visited = set()
        visited.add(src)
        while (len(queue) > 0):
            curr = queue.pop(0)

            for vertex in self.vertList[curr]:
                if vertex not in visited:
                    queue.append(vertex)
                    visited.add(vertex)
                    distanceDict[vertex] = distanceDict[curr] + 1

        print(distanceDict[target])



    def solveSnakesLadder(self):
        snakeLadderDict = {2: 13, 5: 2, 9: 18, 18: 11, 17: -13, 20: -14, 24: -8, 25: 10, 32: -2, 34: -22}
        # we have 36 boxes --> i
        # we can throw a dice at each of these 36 boxes and it can be from 1 to 6
        # j is new position on the board after throwing a dice
        for i in range(0, 37):
            for dice in range(1, 7):
                j = i + dice
                if j in snakeLadderDict:
                    j += snakeLadderDict[j]
                if j <= 36:
                    self.addEdge(i, j)
        self.distanceBFS(0, 36)


g = Graph()
g.solveSnakesLadder()
```

Comment: Hey, the output is still stuck at 10!

Comment: Strange, I get `4` with the above code. please verify if you have missed anything.

Comment: Can you edit the answer and upload the full code too? thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two errors in your algorithm. The most important is here:

```
distanceDict[vertex] = distanceDict[curr] + 1
```

This may overwrite an existing distance with a worse one. So you should do:

```
distanceDict[vertex] = min(distanceDict[vertex], distanceDict[curr] + 1)
```

And, there is one vertex missing in `distanceDict`, since node 36 has no outgoing edges. This is maybe not really an error, but an omission. But it is logical that you would have an entry for *all* nodes in your graph. So you should deal with that, for instance by initialising:

```
distanceDict[target] = INT_MAX
```

It would also be a good idea to exit the loop when you have found the target, so to avoid unnecessarily visiting all other nodes, which can never change the outcome.

Finally, it is not necessary to keep track of each node's distance from the source, nor is it needed to use a queue. If you separate each "level" of the BFS traversal tree, then you can use a new list for each level, and increment a single distance variable to keep track of it.

```
def distanceBFS(self, src, target):
    distance = 0
    visited = set()
    frontier = [src]
    while frontier:
        if target in frontier:
            return distance  # found
        visited.update(frontier)
        frontier = [vertex for curr in frontier for vertex in self.vertList[curr] 
                               if vertex not in visited]
        distance += 1
    return -1  # cannot be reached
```

Note that this function *returns* the distance, so you still need to print it:

```
print(self.distanceBFS(0, 36))
```